# How ot find out all subclasses in UIKit of UIResponder

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit

I would like to find out all subclasses of UIResponder in UIKit framework.

I can do it via documentation by going over each class in the UIKit framework and checking out "Inherits from"

Comment: Why do you need this? What is your goal? Note that UIApplication, UIViewController, and UIView are the main descendants of UIResponder so all views and view controllers fit.

Comment: @rmaddy I have to list all subclasses of a given class. This time it is UIResponder. Another time it can be UIView.

Comment: @rmaddy I need it to compare all those classes

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all. What are you actually doing? Are you needing something in code or just a list for reference?

Comment: just a list for reference

Answer (score 3):

See this [Apple explanation of Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/WhatIsCocoa/WhatIsCocoa.html), scroll most of the way down for this image:

[image]

Comment: Great document but outdated. Apple should update it.